# Group key-value columns into a single row

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to extract data from a SQLite table that stores key-value pairs in dual columns. For example, with the keys `foo`, `bar`, `man`, and `row`, the table would look like:

```
| _id | external_id | key  | value |
|-----|-------------|------|-------|
| 1   | 12345       | foo  | cow   |
| 2   | 12345       | bar  | moo   |
| 3   | 12345       | man  | hole  |
| 4   | 12345       | row  | boat  |
| 5   | 67980       | foo  | abc   |
| 6   | 67890       | bar  | def   |
| 7   | 67890       | man  | ghi   |
| 8   | 67890       | row  | jkl   |
```

I want to perform a query that gives me each `external_id` in a row with the keys as the columns and the values as the rows. Like this:

```
| external_id | foo |  bar | man  | row  |
|-------------|-----|------|------|------|
| 12345       | cow | moo  | hole | boat |
| 67890       | abc | def  | ghi  | jkl  |
```

The only solution I've been able to come up with is a join for each key:

```
SELECT a.external_id, b.foo, c.bar, d.main, e.row 
FROM myTable AS a
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT external_id, key AS foo
   FROM myTable
   WHERE key="foo") AS b
   ON a.external_id = b.external_id
...
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT external_id, key AS row
   FROM myTable
   WHERE key="row") AS e
   ON a.external_id = e.external_id
GROUP BY a.external_id
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: One of the many reasons that the EAV model is generally a horrible idea in SQL. /soapbox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other available option is to use *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT external_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN key = 'foo' THEN value END) AS foo,
       MAX(CASE WHEN key = 'bar' THEN value END) AS bar,
       MAX(CASE WHEN key = 'man' THEN value END) AS man,
       ... etc
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY external_id
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the collect() method

```
select external_id,
collected_objects['foo'] as foo,
collected_objects['bar'] as bar,
collected_objects['man'] as man,
collected_objects['row'] as row
from(
  select external_id,
  collect(key, value) as collected_objects
  group by external_id)t1
```